# Realm relationship returns nil when it shouldn't

Tags: swift, realm

```
class Book: Object {
    // (…)
    var readingSessions: [ReadingSession] {
        return linkingObjects(ReadingSession.self, forProperty: "book")
    }
}

class ReadingSession: Object {
    // (…)
    var book: Book?

    var aComputedProperty: Int {
        print(self) // Prints ReadingSession { book = Book { (…) } (…) }
        print(self.book) // Prints nil
        // (…)
    }
}
```

The code pretty much says it all. If I print `self` from within my computed property it prints the related object among the other properties like I expect. If I just try to get that object, though, it returns `nil`. Is that supposed to happen? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

Edit: It seems the problem isn't actually related to computed properties. Just calling this from a regular view controller gives me the same problem:

```
let session = ReadingSession()
// (…)
print(session) // This returns every property, including the Book
print(session.book) // This returns nil
```

It doesn't happen always, though. On some parts of my code I do the same thing and it works as expected, in other parts this happens. So I guess I'm just making some silly mistake somewhere, but I have no idea what could be causing this.

---

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let sessions = realm.objects(ReadingSession).filter("book = %@", user.selectedBook!).sorted("date")
let session = sessions[indexPath.row]
print(session.book) // prints nil
session.book = user.selectedBook!
print(session.book) // prints the correct book
```

I don't understand! I'm filtering the sessions based on a `Book`. When I print the filtered session's book shouldn't it return the book I used to filter it? But it only works if I set its book property to that same book again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to declare the `user` property as `dynamic var` to make this work:

```
class ReadingSession: Object {
    dynamic var book: Book?
    //...
}
```

Comment: I thought I already had a relationship when I defined `var book: Book?` in my reading sessions, and then I used the `linkingObjects` part to define an inverse relationship. I thought it wasn't necessary to add a list property to `Book` besides that. You're saying I should have another property for the reading sessions besides that inverse relationship defined with `linkingObjects`? Also, my problem is not querying all sessions from a certain book call, that already works. What doesn't work sometimes is querying a book from a session.

Comment: But books are added to sessions correctly, since I get the right ones when I `print(session)`. The problem is when I `print(session.book)`, then sometimes I get nil. I thought I didn't even need an inverse relationship from `Book` to `ReadingSession` to do that. Each of my `ReadingSessions` has a single `Book` and I just want to get it.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then I misunderstood your question. One question: what type is `user.selectedBook`? Is that a `Book` object?

Comment: Yes, it is, and I also tried adding the book in different ways, like with `objectForPrimaryKey`. Either way the correct book seems to be added to the session, since when I `print(session)` I can see it among the printed properties. But if I `print(section.book)` directly I get nil unless I specify the book again just before calling it.

Comment: Also on that last code example I query just ReadingSessions with a specific book. So their book should be the book I used to filter them. Still I get `nil` unless I specify the book again right after that. But every other property except the `book` relationship works as expected.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I knew it was something silly. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy!